# Rename files without "-n" in the file name

Tags: string, batch-file, file-rename

In *c:\users\microsoft\video\folder1* , I have a huge list of .mp4 files with "-n" (n stands for number).
 E.g:

> Superman-1.mp4
>   Batman-2.mp4
>   Spiderman-3.mp4
>   Ironman-4.mp4
>   And so on...

I want to remove all the "-n" and rename the file only with the "real" name.

> Superman-1.mp4 --> Superman.mp4

I'd tried substring and string replacement (`!substr:~-2,2! & !vidfile:%substr%=!`), but it won't work for all because it will fail when "n" is greater than 9 (which left "-" in the string). I'd also considered to use `if` condition but it seems to have more nested `if` statements than I thought.
Could this be done in a simpler way? An answer will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing text from the middle of a file name with batch renaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081138/removing-text-from-the-middle-of-a-file-name-with-batch-renaming)

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B *.mp4') do ren %%a-%%b %%a.mp4`